# Garbage collection in Guice

Tags: java, garbage-collection, guice

Does GoogleGuice injector keep references of all objects it is creating? If that is the case, how and when are objects created by the injector garbage collected?

To add more context, I have FactoryModuleBuilder creating a Factory as this:

```
`install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(ResourceAccessorFactory.class));`
```

and then using the factory to create instances of object by passing the constructor argument as this:

`ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = ResourceAccessorFactory.create(abc);`

In this case, will injector keep on holding a reference to the object 'resourceAccessor'. If that is the case, the object will never be garbage collected and the service will run out of memory (since I am creating an instance of the object at every call)

Comment: suppose not, what could be reason to keep?

Comment: @Jacek Cz: I don't want the injector to keep holding references to the objects it creates. I just want to confirm that it indeed is the case.                   To add more context, I have Factory

Comment: @Jacek Cz: I don't want the injector to keep holding references to the objects it creates. I just want to confirm that it indeed is the case.                   My concern is that if the injector keeps holding the reference, the object will never be garbage collected. I have added more explanation in the question.

Comment: hard to imagine. Can You post some readable code (i.e syntax formatted), showing problem?

Comment: In general Singleton and around, factory and similar patterns have some risk of memory leak (in Java sense), but usually with not-professional (not educated) coding. Memory leak IS NOT NORM

Comment: @@Jacek Cz: added code snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152114/discussion-between-nitesh-kumar-and-jacek-cz).

Answer (score 0):

Guice injector does not keep references to your objects. Also, the provider created by FactoryModuleBuilder does not not keep reference to objects it creates for you.

As long as you do not keep references to your object, and your object is not @Singleton, it will be garbage collected. @Singleton objects will stick around until the injector is garbage collected.

You really wan't to understand guice scopes: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes